# QGIS 3.16 shapefile features not visible

Tags: qgis, features, filter

A point shapefile with the project CRS has 66 digitized features (point count is 66). The attribute table header reflects the point number; and that there are 7 points filtered. (I have no idea how the filtering happened). Attribute table and map only show the 7 filtered records or points respectively. Zoom to only covers the small area of filtered points. On export, only the filtered features are exported. Exactly how can the entire 66 points be retrieved?

Comment: Go to `Project properties (right-click on the layer) > Source Tab` and check if there is an `Feature filter` activated.

Comment: Thank you Vince, nothing was there. Ended up losing the points in the feature count, so just re-digitized.